# Git Checkout master - Not Working

Tags: git, git-checkout

Here is scenario, my local branch is `development`:

```
> $ git status
> On branch development 
> nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Here is all the branches:

```
> $ git branch   
> configuration
> * development
> hotfix-1.2
> master
> release-1.0
```

Now if i do checkout to master, it shows me this:

```
> $ git checkout master
> error: Your local changes to the following files
> would be overwritten by checkout:
>         .htaccess
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
> Aborting
```

Note: i put .htaccess file in .gitignore because production server has different than staging

Answer (score 1):

hey you had change something in **.htaccess** file, which is in .gitignore

1. You can stash it using `git stash`
2. Or If you want changes in that file you can commit it.

   `git commit -m "add .htaccess file"`

Then try to checkout on Master branch. hope it will help :)

Comment: Thanks, but there's nothing in my stash when i try to 'git stash' neither any change when i do 'git status'.

Comment: ```error: Your local changes to the following files
> would be overwritten by checkout:
>  .htaccess
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
> Aborting```



This message say's there are something changed in your local repo.. which eigther need to be commit or stash